# Login with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

Is it possible to bind the login-processing-url to POST requests only?

I would like to use GET to show the login formular and trigger the login process with POST only, something like

`<security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login" />`

Comment: No, not without changing quite a lot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security 3.2's Java Configuration does this by default. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form

If you want to do this with XML configuration or versions prior to Spring Security 3.2 then, as Luke mentions, it is quite a bit more complicated.

NOTE: Right now Spring Security 3.2 is only available in a release candidate versions, but a GA version is scheduled for release later this month.